# Локальный чат на react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть такая задача и как сделать все это без серверной части в рамках одного браузера
Создать веб-приложение - локальный чат
·   Чат должен работать без сервера, в рамках одного браузера.
·   У каждой вкладки своя сессия.
·   При в ходе в чат пользователь должен идентифицировать себя и комнату чата в которую он хочет войти.
·   Сообщения от других пользователей должны появляться без перезагрузки вкладки.
·   Данные чата должны сохраняться и восстанавливаться при входе пользователя в комнату.
·   Данные пользователя и сообщения должны храниться локально и не удаляться при закрытии браузера.

Comment: Попробуйте организовать хранилище сообщений через localStorage. у localStorage есть события изменения, которые можно слушать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервер так или иначе у вас будет, но в вашем случае локальный

На счёт данных, полагаю вы хотите обойтись без БД? В таком случае, задача усложняется. Вы можете хранить данные переписок (и сессии пользователей) через localStorage/Cookie, и обмениваться этими данными с другими пользователями. Получится что-то похожее на торрент-сеть, где у каждого есть какие-то данные (скорее всего осортированные по ID или метке времени), и этими данными клиенты обмениваются для просмотра истории чата. Естественно тут нужно проверять корректность данных, их уникальность и достоверность

Comment: Если БД будет, то задача существенно легче

Comment: Спасибо большое, у меня задача все сделать в рамках фронта без сервера и бд, такого условие. это тестовое задание для работы

Comment: @ПетяГерман довольно сложное задание, как по мне. Я не имею опыта в реализации подобного, но полагаю что вам нужно смотреть в сторону вебсокетов и т.п. Возможно эта статья чем-то поможет - https://habr.com/ru/post/544046/

Comment: Как я понял нужно без использования каких либо библиотек, потому что тут используется сервер